# How to handle many-to-many relationships with ASP.NET Core Identity in a Clean Architecture project?

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity, clean-architecture, navigation-properties

I'm working on a project that follows the Clean Architecture pattern, and I'm using ASP.NET Core Identity to handle authentication and authorization. I have a `User` entity that inherits from `IdentityUser`, and I need to establish many-to-many relationships with other entities in the domain.

The problem is that I can't add a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore` to the domain layer, as it would violate the dependency rule. Therefore, I decided to move the `User` class to the infrastructure layer, where I can have a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore`. However, this created a new issue, as I can't use navigation properties to configure the relationships with other entities from the domain layer.

What's the best approach to handle this situation? Should I move the User class back to the domain layer, even if it means violating the dependency rule? Or is there a way to configure many-to-many relationships without navigation properties, while keeping the User class in the infrastructure layer?

I'd appreciate any guidance on this topic. Thank you!

I want to use navigation properties freely. But I don't I want to violate essential rules.

Comment: But your `DbContext` inherits `IdentityDbContext` so you're going to have this problem anyway

Comment: I do not have any trouble with `DbContext`. My problem is with *using navigation properties*, while configuring a data relation with my custom Identity models which inherited from `IdentityUser` or others.